# Не могу понять, почему поле RES в htop / top не соответствует количеству использованной памяти

Tags: linux, ассемблер, yasm

С помощью системного вызова **mmap** я попросил ОС выделить мне 4096 * 100000 байт памяти (то есть 100 тыс. страниц). Это 390.625 MiB. **htop** показывает в столбце VIRT 390M.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вроде похоже на правду. Я заполняю 8192 байт (2 страницы) первых элементов выделенной мне памяти       и RES равен 4. И top и htop показывают одинаковое значение 4 KiB. Как такое возможно? Я заполнил массив на 8 KiB, а получил 4 KiB физической памяти?
Возможно, я как-то неправильно интерпретирую значение RES или неверно пользуюсь **mmap**?

Вот исходный код:

```asm
section .data

SYS_read equ 0
SYS_mmap equ 9
SYS_exit equ 60
PROT_READ equ 0x1
PROT_WRITE equ 0x2
MAP_ANONYMOUS equ 0x0020
MAP_PRIVATE equ 0x0002
EXIT_SUCCESS equ 0
STDIN equ 0
NULL equ 0
PAGE_SIZE equ 4096

section .text
global _start
_start:
; allocate ~390MB of heap memory
  mov rax, SYS_mmap
  mov rdi, NULL
  mov rsi, PAGE_SIZE * 100000
  mov rdx, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE
  mov r10, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS
  mov r8, -1
  mov r9, 0
  syscall

; fill 2 pages with values
  mov rbx, rax
  xor rcx, rcx
lbl:
  mov byte[rbx + rcx], cl
  inc rcx
  cmp rcx, 8192
  jl lbl
  
; wait until key pressed  
  mov rax, SYS_read
  mov rdi, STDIN
  lea rsi, byte [rbx]
  mov rdx, 1
  syscall

; exit  
  mov rax, SYS_exit
  mov rdi, EXIT_SUCCESS
  syscall
```

Собираю бинарник так: `> yasm -f elf64 sample.asm` `> ld sample.o`

Прошу помочь разобраться! Как минимум я ожидал увидеть значение 8 KiB в столбце RES. Но ведь и сам код занимает место! Значит должно быть больше 8?

UPDATE: в комментариях попросили показать содержимое `/proc/$pid/smaps`

```
00400000-00401000 r--p 00000000 08:12 11284375                           /home/alex/dev/src/asm/sandbox/a.out
Size:                  4 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Rss:                   0 kB
Pss:                   0 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         0 kB
Referenced:            0 kB
Anonymous:             0 kB
LazyFree:              0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FilePmdMapped:        0 kB
Shared_Hugetlb:        0 kB
Private_Hugetlb:       0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
SwapPss:               0 kB
Locked:                0 kB
THPeligible:        0
VmFlags: rd mr mw me dw sd 
00401000-00402000 r-xp 00001000 08:12 11284375                           /home/alex/dev/src/asm/sandbox/a.out
Size:                  4 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Rss:                   4 kB
Pss:                   4 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         4 kB
Private_Dirty:         0 kB
Referenced:            4 kB
Anonymous:             0 kB
LazyFree:              0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FilePmdMapped:        0 kB
Shared_Hugetlb:        0 kB
Private_Hugetlb:       0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
SwapPss:               0 kB
Locked:                0 kB
THPeligible:        0
VmFlags: rd ex mr mw me dw sd 
7fa00207d000-7fa01a71d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
Size:             400000 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Rss:                   8 kB
Pss:                   8 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         8 kB
Referenced:            8 kB
Anonymous:             8 kB
LazyFree:              0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FilePmdMapped:        0 kB
Shared_Hugetlb:        0 kB
Private_Hugetlb:       0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
SwapPss:               0 kB
Locked:                0 kB
THPeligible:        0
VmFlags: rd wr mr mw me ac sd 
7ffeaf308000-7ffeaf329000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
Size:                132 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Rss:                   8 kB
Pss:                   8 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         8 kB
Referenced:            8 kB
Anonymous:             8 kB
LazyFree:              0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FilePmdMapped:        0 kB
Shared_Hugetlb:        0 kB
Private_Hugetlb:       0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
SwapPss:               0 kB
Locked:                0 kB
THPeligible:        0
VmFlags: rd wr mr mw me gd ac 
7ffeaf3e3000-7ffeaf3e7000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
Size:                 16 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Rss:                   0 kB
Pss:                   0 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         0 kB
Referenced:            0 kB
Anonymous:             0 kB
LazyFree:              0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FilePmdMapped:        0 kB
Shared_Hugetlb:        0 kB
Private_Hugetlb:       0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
SwapPss:               0 kB
Locked:                0 kB
THPeligible:        0
VmFlags: rd mr pf io de dd sd 
7ffeaf3e7000-7ffeaf3e9000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
Size:                  8 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Rss:                   0 kB
Pss:                   0 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         0 kB
Referenced:            0 kB
Anonymous:             0 kB
LazyFree:              0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FilePmdMapped:        0 kB
Shared_Hugetlb:        0 kB
Private_Hugetlb:       0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
SwapPss:               0 kB
Locked:                0 kB
THPeligible:        0
VmFlags: rd ex mr mw me de sd 
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 --xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Size:                  4 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Rss:                   0 kB
Pss:                   0 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         0 kB
Referenced:            0 kB
Anonymous:             0 kB
LazyFree:              0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FilePmdMapped:        0 kB
Shared_Hugetlb:        0 kB
Private_Hugetlb:       0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
SwapPss:               0 kB
Locked:                0 kB
THPeligible:        0
VmFlags: ex
```

Comment: Приложил в описание вопроса

Comment: интересный вопрос... в `smaps` данные похожи на правду, но такое ощущение, что в RSS для всего процесса они не всегда поддерживаются в актуальном состоянии... или как-то по-другому чуднО считаются...

Comment: Причем если я заполню 8193 байта, то smaps покажет Rss 12 kB в выделенном мне блоке, а top/htop всё ещё будут показывать 4. То есть с htop/top что-то не так получается? или надо тюнить как-то их?

Comment: `top`/`htop` просто показывают данные из `/proc/PID/stat` и `status` — их тюнинг ничего не изменит... надо смотреть, как в ядре эта статистика собирается и обновляется...

Comment: Действительно, в `/proc/$pid/status` показывается `VmRSS: 4 kB`. Почему - непонятно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ps`/`top`/`htop` просто показывают данные из файлов `/proc/PID/stat`, `statm` и `status`. В них показывается информация, собираемая ядром. Однако в linux начиная с 2.6.34 значения `RSS` для всего процесса обновляется не при каждом запросе/освобождении памяти, а только когда количество событий (в основном страничных прерываний) для данного потока превысит определённый предел (конкретно говоря — [`64`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/memory.c#L192)). Как подмечено в [документации](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/proc.html) ядра:

> For making accounting scalable, RSS related information are handled in an asynchronous manner and the value may not be very precise. To see a precise snapshot of a moment, you can see /proc//smaps file and scan page table. It’s slow but very precise.

Вольный перевод:

> Для того, чтобы сделать подсчёты более масштабируемыми, информация, связанная с RSS обрабатывается асинхронно, так что эти значения могут быть не очень точны. Чтобы получить точные значения, вы можете обратиться к файлу `/proc/<pid>/smaps` и произвести подсчёт по таблице страниц. Это медленно, зато очень точно.

Как утверждается в оригинальном [коммите](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/34e55232e59f7b19050267a05ff1226e5cd122a5), такой подход уменьшает количество кеш-промахов на страничное прерывание при агрессивном обращении к памяти из двух потоков с `4.5` до `4.0`.

Таким образом, максимальная ошибка, которую может показывать значение `RSS` в `/proc/PID/stat` (а также в `ps`/`top`/`htop`) составляет до 256К (64 страницы * 4K) на каждый поток.

Answer (score 1):

`ps`/`top` берут данные из  `/proc/[pid]/stat` (смотрите [man](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/procfs.5.html) ):

> Status information about the process.  This is used by ps(1).

По полю rss там написано: `This value is inaccurate; see /proc/[pid]/statm below`

А там пишут:

> Some of these values are inaccurate because of a kernel-
> internal scalability optimization.  If accurate values are
> required, use /proc/[pid]/smaps or
> /proc/[pid]/smaps_rollup instead, which are much slower
> but provide accurate, detailed information.

Очевидно точность в top принесена в жертву скорости.

Comment: Интересно, что судя по всему это дополнение в man'е появилось после того как его [пытались сделать](https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/1133454/) опциональным в ядре.